# Difference between split() and tokenize()

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tokenize

I am counting the number of unique words in a loaded text file. However I have realized that when I use `split()` and tensorflow_datasets `tokenize()` I get different results yet I thought they achieve the same thing. Here is my code. Can somebody help me know the difference between the two.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

tf.enable_eager_execution()

BUFFER_SIZE = 50000
TAKE_SIZE = 5000
BATCH_SIZE = 64

tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()
data = open("news.2011.en.shuffled","r").read()
vocab = list(set(data.split()))  # gives more count
print(len(vocab))

tokenized_data = tokenizer.tokenize(data)
print(len(set(tokenized_data)))  # gives less count
```

Comment: This [blog](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/groovy-tokenize-vs-split/#:~:text=tokenize()%20%2Cwhich%20returns%20a,split()%20keeps%20such%20string.&text=The%20split()%20can%20take,where%20as%20tokenize%20does%20not.) also gives a nice summary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split()` function when passed with no parameter splits only based on white-space characters present in the string.

The `tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()`'s `tokenize()` method has more ways of splitting text rather than only white space character. You can see that in the GitHub [code repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/tensorflow_datasets/core/features/text/text_encoder.py#L387). At present, there is no default `reserved_tokens` set but the property of `alphanum_only` is set to True by default.

Hence, potentially many of the non alpha-numeric characters are getting filtered out and hence you are getting less number of tokens.

Comment: Btw, the github link no longer exists.